# Spring sleuth kafkaTemplate injections

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-sleuth

Have a project with spring boot 2.1.9, spring kafka and spring sleuth (2.1.6).

All's been going well till I reached the point of tracing messages to/from kafka.

Kafka messaging is done through:

```
kafkaTemplate.send(uri, pojo)
```

And here I realized that there is no injection into kafka messaging - both debugged points of `doSend` of Kafka, and printed the message, received from `@KafkaListener` (with looking for keys from `brave...KafkaKeys`), and never saw a note of tracing.

As I understand from the doc, these messaging are enabled by default (not that I havent enabling "messaging" or "integration").

Tried registering custom bean implementations of "Propagation.Setter" just to see if it's actually being called, and never seen this actually ping.

Additional note: I found that org.apache.kafka(from spring-kafka 2.2.9) ...KafkaProducer is used instead of Sleuth one's.

What am I missing?

Comment: The KafkaTemplate should have the producer factory instrumented. You can check the `SleuthKafkaAspect` class for what it instruments. You could see if any of the aspect instrumentation parts are applied.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see this class anywhere. Using `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin` Greenwich.SR4

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/TraceMessagingAutoConfiguration.java#L209

Comment: Seems to be some conflict with AOP in the project. Realized that `@Aspect` isn't processed properly.

Comment: Please create a sample that replicates the issue

Comment: Finally found the coulprid - there was a spot where the `KafkaProducerFactory` was created as new and inside another bean.